# Proof for linear algebra book question

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I was doing some linear algebra questions from to understand the subject better after having learned it terribly and barely remembering anything about the subject. So, I come into this proof question and it is fascinating to prove, and I'm stuck, but I really want to figure this out. I feel like there is something easy I'm missing. 
 Show that if $$a \neq b$$, then
     $$a^{n} + a^{n-1}b + a^{n-2}b^2 + ...+ ab^{n-1} + b^{n} = \frac{a^{n + 1} - b^{n + 1}}{a - b}$$

What I have tried:

I have realized that this problem can be written as 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a^n & a^{n-1} & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
b^{1} \\
.\\
.\\
.\\
b^{n}
\end{bmatrix} = \frac{a^{n + 1} - b^{n + 1}}{a - b}$$
This was a pdf copy I found online, so maybe some parts of the text are missing. I will presume $n \geq 0$ where n is an integer and a and b are real numbers, and I also tried using induction based off summation notation $\sum_{i = 0}^n a^{n - i} b^{i} = \frac{a^{n + 1} - b^{n + 1}}{a - b}$, but I realized that doesn't work. So, yeah, I'm not sure how to prove this but I'm intrigued by it and I haven't seen any solution from my book. This is a question from Elementary Linear Algebra by Howard Anton and Chris Rorres textbook. If this is a repeat question please let me know. All help appreciated!

Comment: Just multiply both sides by $a-b$ ($\ne0$) and compare

Comment: Thank You! That made sense. So, basically all the terms cancel out besides $a^{n+1}$ and $-b^{n + 1}$, and you are basically left with the numerator of the right side.